# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when project deployed to staging, works fine locally

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asmx, webmethod

We are currently uploading a photo to a `WebMethod` via `javascript` everything works perfectly fine on local.

Yet when I deploy this to staging we get the following exception: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` Our `javascript` method is as follows:

```
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', $('#photo')[0].files[0]); // Image
   formData.append('c', i);
   formData.append('t', t);
   formData.append('i', uuid);

      $.ajax({
          url: "/member/myserice/test.asmx/UploadImage",
          type: "POST",
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          data: formData,
          success: function (response) {
              alert('success');
          },
          error: function (er) {
            alert('Unable to upload photo at this time, please try again later');
          }
        });
```

Now as you can see we store the uploaded image inside formData (first parameter)

Our `WebMethod` is as follows:

```
  public string UploadImage()
  {

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        var timestamp = httpRequest.Form["t"];
        var consumerId = httpRequest.Form["c"];
        var guid = httpRequest.Form["i"];
        var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];

        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pic.FileName); // Breaks here when deployed to staging

        var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(pic.FileName);

       //Removed additional code as it calls an external API.

  }
```

Now as mentioned before this works perfectly fine on local, yet when deployed to staging I get the exception `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` on the following line:

```
  string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pic.FileName);
```

Now I've tried searching the web for a given solution or an detailed explanation into why and how to fix but with no avail, can someone shed some light into what if needs be I need change to get this to function correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This works locally because both client and server use the same file system and path from `$('#photo')[0].files[0]` point to same file on server. You shouldn't try to read file from file system on server side, but use the file stream from HttpContext

---

Instead of

```
    var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pic.FileName); // Breaks here when deployed to staging
    var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(pic.FileName);
```

Use the file stream uploaded from client:

```
var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(pic.InputStream);
```

Comment: I've changed the code to now look like the following: var pic = httpRequest.Form["file"]; but this highlights a few errors one being on string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pic.FileName); says string does not contain a definition FileName

Comment: You don't need to try get the file from the file system. You should get stream or byte array from HttpContext. I can't provide more detailed example now (writing from mobile, sorry)

Comment: No problem, let me have a dig and see if I can find some information on the web. Will update accordingly